# How can I identify the name of the last played xscreensaver?

Tags: screensaver, xscreensaver

Is there a way to identify the name of which screensaver was last playing an xscreensaver session? Is there a log or of which screensaver played last in xscreensaver, in a scriptfile or on the system somewhere? If, for example, you have it set to cycle or random?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there is a way to show this information via a log, and it is usually used for debugging purposes. Your user session, whether it is Gnome or Xfce, will usually auto-load `xscreensaver` with the options `xscreensaver -no-splash &`, as it does in Xfce, for example, using the file `/etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc`.

**Temporary Setting**

So if you want to load up `xscreensaver` with different options just for that session (until you log out), you can kill any running instances with

```
killall xscreensaver
```

and then launch it with the appropriate new parameters:

```
xscreensaver -verbose -no-splash -log /home/$USER/xscreen2.log &
```

This command launches the `xscreensaver` daemon process with the verbose option so that it reports on exactly what it does, which is then saved in the specified log.

For this experiment, run `xscreensaver-demo` to set the screensaver options to random, and choose very low 'blank after' and 'cycle after' values in the settings. Now  when the timeout you specified is reached, `xscreensaver` will start and write to the log. (The settings changed by `xscreensaver-demo` are saved in `~/.xscreensaver`.)

**More 'permanent' setting** (example used is for Xfce)

**If** you want `xscreensaver` to always save its data to a log (passwords used to unlock screens are not copied to the log), first copy xfce4's systemwide `xinitrc` to your home folder:

```
cp /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc $HOME/.config/xfce4/xinitrc
```

Now change the two occurences of

```
xscreensaver -no-splash &
```

at around lines 199 and 208 (in my version) to

```
xscreensaver -verbose -no-splash -log /home/$USER/xscreen1.log &
```

If you want to revert to the default setting, just change the commands back in the file or delete `$HOME/.config/xfce4/xinitrc` so that no custom xfce4 `xinitrc` settings are applied on login.

(You will have to logout and login for this setting to take effect)

A sample of the log created contains **just** what you were looking for: a way of identifying which screensavers were playing in a random session (I have shortened the log as it is extremely verbose)

```
xscreensaver 5.15, copyright (c) 1991-2008 by Jamie Zawinski <jwz@jwz.org>.
xscreensaver: 00:55:14: 0: spawning "glschool -root" in pid 8392.
xscreensaver: 00:56:14: 0: killing pid 8392 (glschool)
xscreensaver: 00:56:14: 0: visual 0x21 (TrueColor,   depth: 24, cmap: 256)
xscreensaver: 00:56:14: 0: saver window is 0x2e0000c.
xscreensaver: 00:56:14: 0: destroyed old saver window 0x2e00009.
xscreensaver: 00:56:14: 0: spawning "glmatrix -root" in pid 8393.
xscreensaver: 00:56:14: 0: child pid 8392 (glschool) terminated with signal 15.
xscreensaver: 00:57:14: 0: killing pid 8393 (glmatrix)
xscreensaver: 00:57:14: 0: visual 0x21 (TrueColor,   depth: 24, cmap: 256)
xscreensaver: 00:57:14: 0: saver window is 0x2e0000f.
xscreensaver: 00:57:14: 0: destroyed old saver window 0x2e0000c.
xscreensaver: 00:57:14: 0: child pid 8393 (glmatrix) terminated with signal 15.
xscreensaver: 00:57:14: 0: spawning "fiberlamp -root" in pid 8395.
xscreensaver: 00:58:14: 0: killing pid 8395 (fiberlamp)
xscreensaver: 00:58:14: 0: child pid 8395 (fiberlamp) terminated with signal 15.
xscreensaver: 00:58:14: 0: visual 0x21 (TrueColor,   depth: 24, cmap: 256)
xscreensaver: 00:58:14: 0: saver window is 0x2e00012.
xscreensaver: 00:58:14: 0: destroyed old saver window 0x2e0000f.
xscreensaver: 00:58:14: 0: spawning "fuzzyflakes -root" in pid 8396.
```

For more information, see `man xscreensaver`, `man xscreensaver-demo`, and the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xscreensaver.1.html).